# Не запускается файл kv (kivy)

Tags: python, framework, kivy

Только начал работать с kivy, и решил пользоваться их языком. Но не запускается файл kv, хотя читал что для его работы, ничего толком и делать не нужно. Может я что то не так понял, подскажите.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MessageApp(App):
    def Build(self):
        return Label()


MessageApp().run()
```

Знаю что нужно 4 пробела у text. Каких то еще требований для такой банальной задачи вроде нет. Ошибок о том что не может запустить файл, тоже нет. Пользуюсь Pycharm, сам kivy установлен (debian) , и все методы работают.

```
<Label>
   text:"hello world!"
```

P.S. само гуи запускается, не подхватывает kv файл почему то.

Comment: где должен подхватываться файл `.kv`?

Comment: Они оба лежат в одной папке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Главный клас, унаследованный от App должен содержать метод build и возвращать какой-либо виджет. Так что вопрос о kv файлах в данном контексте неуместен.

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 
from kivy.lang import Builder 
from kivy.properties import StringProperty 


Builder.load_string(''' 
#: import MDFlatButton kivymd.button.MDFlatButton 

# Данные инструкции в Kivy-Language аналогичны импорту в python сценариях: 
# from kivymd.button import MDFlatButton 
# 
# В kv-файле вы можете включать другие файлы разметки, 
# если интерфейс, например, слишком сложный: #: include your_kv_file.kv 
#
# Стандартные виджеты и контроллы, предоставляемые Kivy из коробки,
# не нужно импортировать в Activity — просто используйте их.

# Все элементы данного Activity будут располагаться в BoxLayout - 
# виджете, от которого унаследован базовый класс. 
<StartScreen> 

    MDFlatButton: 
        id: button 
        text: 'Press Me' 
        size_hint_x: 1  # относительная ширина контролла - от 0 до 1 
        pos_hint: {'y': .5}  # положение контролла относительно вертикали 'y' корневого виджета 

        # Событие контролла. 
        on_release: 
            # Ключевое слово 'root' - это инстанс базового класса разметки, 
            # через который вы можете получить доступ ко всем его методам и атрибутам. 
            root.set_text_on_button() 
''') 
# Или Builder.load_file('path/to/kv-file'), 
# если разметка Activity находится в файле. 


class StartScreen(BoxLayout): 
    '''Базовый класс.''' 

    new_text_for_button = StringProperty() 
    # В Kivy вы должны явно указывать тип атрибутов: 
    # 
    # StringProperty; 
    # NumericProperty; 
    # BoundedNumericProperty; 
    # ObjectProperty; 
    # DictProperty; 
    # ListProperty; 
    # OptionProperty; 
    # AliasProperty; 
    # BooleanProperty; 
    # ReferenceListProperty; 
    # 
    # в противном случае вы получите ошибку 
    # при установке значений этих атрибутов. 
    # 
    # Например, если не указывать тип: 
    # 
    # new_text_for_button = '' 
    # 
    # будет возбуждено исключение - 
    # TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters. 

    def set_text_on_button(self): 
        self.ids.button.text = self.new_text_for_button 
        # ids - это словарь всех объектов Activity 
        # которым назначен идентификатор. 
        # 
        # Так, обратившись через идентификатор 'button' - self.ids.button - 
        # к объекту кнопки, мы получаем доступ 
        # ко всем его методам и атрибутам. 

    # Любой атрибут, инициализировванный как Properties, 
    # автоматически получает метод в базовом классе с префиксом 'on_', 
    # который будет вызван как только данный атрибут получит новое значение. 
    def on_new_text_for_button(self, instance, value): 
        print(instance, value) 


class Program(App): 
    def build(self): 
        '''Метод, вызываемый при старте программы. 
        Должен возвращать объект создаваемого Activity.''' 

        return StartScreen(new_text_for_button='This new text') 


if __name__ in ('__main__', '__android__'): 
    Program().run()  # запуск приложения
```

Конкретно по вашему примеру... Вы создаете Activity (kv file), который должен иметь базовый класс с таким же именем, как ваш шаблон разметки:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string('''
<MyActivity>:
    Label:
        text:"hello world!
''')


class MyActivity(BoxLayout):
    pass


class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyActivity()


Test().run()
```

Или без базового класса:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder


Activity = '''
<MyActivity@BoxLayout>:
    Label:
        text:"hello world!
'''


class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(Activity)


Test().run()
```

https://habrahabr.ru/users/heattheatr/topics/ - блог о разработке с Kivy.

Answer (score 0):

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App


class MessageApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MessageApp().run()
```

**message.kv**

```
Label:
   text:"hello world!"
```

Comment: Попробывал, if не срабатывает, а без него тоже самое.

Answer (score 0):

из последнего примера получил hello world.внимательно следите за расположением
файлов в директории.Pycharm in windows.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]